# How to pass prop which depends on another prop?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I have `fullscreen: () => void` prop which calls the fullscreen function. This function is not available in all browsers. What is the recommended way to convey this information to child?

1. I can send another boolean prop
2. I can pass NoOp and check for it in child
3. ??? Anything else ???

The child will show/hide fullscreen UI element based on the value it gets

Comment: Why should the child care? Pass a no-op and let the child call it, *it's a no-op*.

Comment: The child handles the UI so the fullscreen icon must be removed if api is not available

Comment: Either pass a function or nothing/undefined, so the child can test it for truthiness.